# Block everything except one div

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-blockui

I need to use blockUI with ajax, but it doesn't work for me:

```
      $('#myDiv').block({ message: 'Message Resource' })
```

I want to ensure that my sidebar div is not locked when scroll over the div that I am blocking.

I intend to do some default validation, such that my sidebar div is never blocked, as this is the div menu and intend that this is always available.

Comment: But the side div, it's been blocked or not?

Comment: The zone which comes into contact with the locked div yes.

This side div comes above with slideToggle jquery plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this problem and it was simpler than I thought.

The BlockUI default has z-index to 1000, so I put the div that sits on top of the div that I want to block with a z-index greater than 1000 and works perfectly.